# Split a JavaScript string into pieces of different length

Tags: javascript

I tried to play with `match(/.{1,n}/g);`,  but I cant't reproduce expected result.

Input: `const str = "some string"; const lengths = [4,1,6]`

Output: `['some', '', 'string']`

A possible solution:

```js
 const string = '      1234567'
 const lengths = [4, 2, -1, -3, 2]

 const getSubstrArrayByLengthsArray = (lengthsArray, str) => {
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < lengthsArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (j >= str.length || lengthsArray[i] > str.length) {
            return results;
        }
        if (lengthsArray[i] > 0) {
            results.push(str.substr(j, lengthsArray[i]));
            j += lengthsArray[i];
        } else {
            results.push('');
        }
    }
    return results;
};

console.log(getSubstrArrayByLengthsArray(lengths, string)) // ["    ", "  ", "",
```

Comment: Loop over `lengths`, and use the `substr` method to get the parts …?

Comment: @Vlad - why not produce a [mcve] from the snippet I made you?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const lengths = [4, 1, 6]

const string = "some string"

const parts = lengths.map((len, i) => {
  let prevLen;
  if (i === 0) {
    prevLen = 0
  } else {
    prevLen = lengths.slice(0, i).reduce((sum, l) => sum + l, 0)
  }

  return string.substring(prevLen, len + prevLen)
})

console.log(parts);
```